# How can I override a Foreground property with a Style after initialization?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

So I have a TextBlock-element in my Windows 8 app which I override the foreground color of like this:

```
TestTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0));
```

I would like to override this color at a later point using a style with a different Foreground-color. Style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="MyStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>
```

Override:

```
TestTextBlock.Style = (Style) App.Current.Resources["MyStyle"];
```

Now this works if I *don't* initialize the Foreground-property first. It seems as if Foreground has precedence over Style. Thing is this is a simplified example and I can't remove the code line setting the Foreground-property.

Any other way of working around this? I tried setting Foreground = null, but that resulted in invisible text.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your default color however you want, then personally I run a `ColorAnimation` at it via Storyboard like;

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ChangeThatForegroundColor">
   <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                   Storyboard.TargetName="YourTextBlockName"
                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                   To="Yellow" />
</Storyboard>
```

and you can fire it off with the [BeginStoryboard method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598106%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: That's definitely a solution, but it feels like using the wrong tool for the job. I'll accept it if no other answers come within the next couple of days.

Comment: Eh, it's generally the way it's done at runtime. Hence why your default control templates do it that way also.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help :it works for me

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="TestTextBlock" Text="Hello world"/>
```

1)**override SolidColorBrush with solidcolorbrush only**

```
  void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        TestTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);                       
    }
```

2)**override style with style only**

```
 <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyStyle1" TargetType="TextBlock" >      
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>

  void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        TestTextBlock.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["MyStyle"];
        TestTextBlock.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["MyStyle1"];            
    }
```